# TextView width constraint not working dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-constraintlayout

Why does the `TextView` refuse to move even though I've added the constraints for it? All I want is for the text in the `TextView` to wrap itself with its parent `CardView`. I've already added the following but stillno change:

- `ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP`
- Layout Parameters

[image]

```
class MonFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sv_cl, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view
        val mCLMain = v!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.my_constraintLayout_SV)
        val mCLWarning = ConstraintLayout(context)

        // Layout Parameters
        val rlpIVWarning = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVWarning = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        // Values for DP (density independent pixels) measuring
        val r = context!!.resources
        val fourDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val tenDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()


        /*
         * Creating 'Warning' CardView items
         */
        // 'Warning' icon
        val ivWarning = ImageView(context)
        ivWarning.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_warning)
        ivWarning.layoutParams = rlpIVWarning

        // 'Warning' text
        val tvWarning = TextView(context)
        tvWarning.text = "1 is not the first prime number."
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvWarning, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)
//        tvWarning.width = 0
        tvWarning.layoutParams = rlpTVWarning

        // Creating CardViews
        val cvWarning = context?.let { CardView(it) }
        when {
            cvWarning != null -> {
                cvWarning.radius = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvWarning.setContentPadding(tenDp, tenDp, tenDp, tenDp)
                cvWarning.useCompatPadding = true
                cvWarning.cardElevation = fourDp.toFloat()
            }
        }

        // Generated IDs for views
        cvWarning!!.id = View.generateViewId()
        ivWarning.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvWarning.id = View.generateViewId()

        // Add views to appropriate views
        mCLMain.addView(cvWarning)
        cvWarning.addView(mCLWarning)
        mCLWarning.addView(ivWarning)
        mCLWarning.addView(tvWarning)

        // Constraint Set 1 (for main ConstraintLayout)
        val mConstraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
        mConstraintSet1.clone(mCLMain)
        mConstraintSet1.connect(cvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, mCLMain.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
        mConstraintSet1.connect(cvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, tvTitle.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
        mConstraintSet1.connect(tvTitle.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, cvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
        mConstraintSet1.connect(tvTitle.id, ConstraintSet.START, mCLMain.id, ConstraintSet.START, tenDp)
        mConstraintSet1.connect(tvTitle.id, ConstraintSet.END, mCLMain.id, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
        mConstraintSet1.applyTo(mCLMain)

        // Constraint set 2 (for 'Warning' CardView)
        val mConstraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
        mConstraintSet2.clone(mCLWarning)
        mConstraintSet2.constrainDefaultWidth(ivWarning.id, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP)
        mConstraintSet2.connect(ivWarning.id, ConstraintSet.START, mCLWarning.id, ConstraintSet.START, 0)
        mConstraintSet2.connect(ivWarning.id, ConstraintSet.END, tvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.START, tenDp)
        mConstraintSet2.connect(tvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.START, ivWarning.id, ConstraintSet.END, tenDp)
        mConstraintSet2.connect(tvWarning.id, ConstraintSet.END, mCLWarning.id, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
        mConstraintSet2.applyTo(mCLWarning)

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LayoutParams` for your warning text look wrong to me. You've set the width to be `WRAP_CONTENT`, but you probably want it to instead be `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` instead. This way you can constrain the edges to the warning image and the side of the card.

Also, why are you using `ConstraintLayout` for this? This seems like it would be dramatically easier as a `CardView` containing a `LinearLayout` containing an `ImageView` + `TextView`.

Comment: More LinearLayouts will be added in future hence trying to avoid too much nesting as it's bad for performance but if I'm wrong I'll give that a go instead.

Comment: I think people get worked up about nested layouts and bad performance way too far before they should. You definitely don't want ten levels of nesting across thousands of views (especially if layout_weight is involved), but 2-3 levels of nesting across tens of views will have no practical effect on performance. I think your first instinct should always be to make the code as easy to maintain/understand as possible, and only begin to sacrifice this for performance if you have **measured** and determined that what you're doing is too slow.

Comment: Ah, ok. Would you say [this fragment I made earlier](https://pastebin.com/22smZ8H2) is too nested?

Comment: Before I get too far into that, why are you using kotlin instead of declaring these layouts in xml?

Comment: I’m trying to avoid the 64K method limit

Comment: Hm, perhaps I'm missing something, but if anything this seems like it adds more methods. Anything you can do in XML means you can remove java/kotlin code.